# How to Make azure-pipeline.yml for CI for a R package?

Tags: r, azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have been trying to get an Azure pipeline working for my companies internal R packages. I would like the pipeline to:

1. `Check()` the package
2. Run the tests in /testthat
3. Check code coverage with covr

We use Azure DevOps and use the Azure Repos within that. The few examples I find mainly focus on GitHub solutions. I have tried working with https://github.com/r-lib/r-azure-pipelines, however, with not a lot of knowledge on how to set up pipelines in the first place I find it very difficult to learn and move forward. I have also posted on RStudio Community [here](https://community.rstudio.com/t/creating-an-azure-pipelines-yml-for-azure-devops-testing-packages-shiny-scripts/32471), however my current method does not run `check()`. I want to try to use all the test functionality that Azure DevOps supplies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Having faced exactly the same challenges with getting Azure pipelines to work with R packages, in two separate organisations, thought I should take the time to share what I've learned along the way.

Please see brief write up and code at https://github.com/jamiegaida/AzurePipelineR

This builds on the great answer above by louish along with other sources. It also runs the lintr package via MegaLinter.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 3):

I needed to do something similar and found your RStudio Community post really useful in getting me started with this - thanks for posting. I have now managed to set up a pipeline which:

1. Checks the package using `rcmdcheck` (this also runs the testthat tests)
2. Runs code coverage with covr
3. Publishes the test results, code coverage report and the check.log file

---

First, you first need to make sure your testthat.R script runs `test_check` with the `reporter` argument specified like so:

`test_check("mypackage", reporter = JunitReporter$new(file = "test-result.xml"))`

---

Then the following .yml file should do the trick:

```
trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

container:
  image: 'rocker/tidyverse:latest'

variables:
  _R_CHECK_FORCE_SUGGESTS_: false
  MAKEFLAGS: "-j 2"

steps:
- bash: R -q -e 'writeLines(".libPaths(\"~/R-private\")", ".Rprofile"); dir.create("~/R-private", recursive = TRUE); print(Sys.getenv());'
  displayName: "Preliminaries"

- bash: R -q -e 'install.packages(c("covr", "roxygen2", "testthat", "remotes", "rcmdcheck")); remotes::install_deps(dependencies = TRUE);'
  displayName: 'Install Dependencies'

- bash: R -q -e "rcmdcheck::rcmdcheck(args = '--no-manual', error_on = 'warning', check_dir = 'check')"
  displayName: 'Check Package'

- bash: R -q -e 'cov <- covr::package_coverage(); covr::to_cobertura(cov, "coverage.xml")'
  displayName: 'Run Code Coverage'
  condition: succeededOrFailed()

- task: UseDotNet@2
  displayName: 'Use .NET Core sdk'
  inputs:
    packageType: sdk
    version: 2.2.203
    installationPath: $(Agent.ToolsDirectory)/dotnet
  condition: succeededOrFailed()

- task: PublishCodeCoverageResults@1
  displayName: 'Publish Code Coverage'
  inputs:
    codeCoverageTool: 'Cobertura'
    summaryFileLocation: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/**/coverage.xml'
  condition: succeededOrFailed()

- task: PublishTestResults@2
  displayName: 'Publish Test Results'
  inputs:
    testResultsFormat: 'JUnit'
    testResultsFiles: '**/test-*.xml'
  condition: succeededOrFailed()

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  displayName: 'Publish Check log'
  inputs:
    pathToPublish: 'check/mypackage.Rcheck/00check.log' 
    artifactName: check 
  condition: succeededOrFailed()
```

Comment: How does this pipeline run the tests? I tried it on my project, but the tests are not running or at least there is not output for them.

Comment: I've just edited the above to use 'ubuntu-latest', previously this was hard-coded to a version no longer supported by Microsoft on Azure. If it wasn't running previously this might help.
If the job runs successfully you should get to a log that says 'X% tests passed' that is hyperlinked to a page that provides more detail on individual tests.